# Красивый вывод дерева

Tags: c++, дерево

Подскажите, как можно красиво вывести это небинарное дерево? Степень узла у него пользовательская

Структура дерева:

```
struct Tree {
    int key = NULL; //ключ
    int index = NULL; //индекс
    int countchild = NULL; //число потомков
    Tree* sibling = nullptr; //братья
    Tree* child = nullptr; //сыновья
};
```

Функция вывода:

```
void print(Tree* Node) // вывод дерева
{
    if (Node->child != NULL) cout << "[+]";
    cout << "(" << Node->index << "-" << Node->key << ")" << endl;
    if (Node->countchild > 0)
        for (int i = 0; i < Node->countchild; i++)
            print((*Node)->child[i]); //вот здесь ошибка [не существует подходящей функции преобразования из Tree в Tree*]
    else return
}
```

Comment: Логично. Зачем вы разыменовали указатель а потом пытаетесь обращаться как по указателю? Должно быть вот так `Node->child[i]` или так `(*Node).child[i]`

Comment: Сорри - вопрос красиво вывести или ошибка в функции вывода?

Comment: Ошибка в функции вывода, кстати попробовал Ваши оба метода - не помогли,[Ошибка точно такая же]
Вопрос был о помощи исправить эту функцию или какое-либо Ваше альтернативеое решение.

Comment: &Node->child[i] - решило проблему

Comment: Странно. А как вы формируете массив `Node->child`? Это динамический массив чего? Объектов типа `Tree` или указателей на объекты типа `Tree`?

Comment: @DmitryK, ну в типе у него массива указателей нет.

Comment: В том-то и косяк! Если это дерево, там должен быть массив указателей на потомков, а не массив потомков.